# Indexing USGS Landsat Collection 2 Level 2 datasets into Open Data Cube

Tags: landsat, usgs, open-data-cube, indexing

I'm trying to ingest data using Landsat 8 Collection 2 Level 2 data into the Open Data Cube, but I couldn't find any examples for data preparation.

How do I index [USGS Landsat Collection 2 datasets](https://registry.opendata.aws/usgs-landsat/) into the Open Data Cube?

Answer (score 4):

You can now index USGS data into the Open Data Cube using the command line tool [STAC API to DC](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-tools/blob/develop/apps/dc_tools/odc/apps/dc_tools/stac_api_to_dc.py)

There are some notes on how to achieve indexing [USGS Collection 2 data here](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/blob/main/usgs-landsat-collection2.md).

A brief howto is as follows:

- Run `datacube product add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/main/products/lsX_c2l2_sr.yaml`  to add the product definition
- Install the tool `pip install odc_apps_dc_tools`
- Run the command below:

```bsh
stac-to-dc \
--catalog-href='https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/' \
--rewrite-assets='https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/data/,s3://usgs-landsat/' \
--bbox='25,20,35,30' \
--collections='landsat-c2l2-sr' \
--datetime='2020-01-01/2020-03-31'
```

This should result in the following message:

> Added 707 Datasets, failed 0 Datasets.

Note that in order to load data, you need to configure [requester pays](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/utilities/generate/datacube.utils.aws.configure_s3_access.html?highlight=requester_pays).

Answer (score 0):

OpenDataCube can index and process LandSat Level 2 Collection 2 data via a STAC v0.7 to v1.0b upgrade and indexing from STAC. There is work in progress in Digital Earth Africa to implement this in an end-to-end fashion. You can follow along here : https://explorer.dev.digitalearth.africa/products/ls8_c2l2/extents

[image]

It shows bits of LANDSAT Collection2 Level2 data indexed in the Digital Earth Africa Datacube.

Feel free to join the ODC slack and as for more implementation details.